# Find overlapping region between two ranges defined by their start and end points

Tags: matlab, octave

How could I find the overlapping region between two ranges defined by their start and end points?
For example, let

```
r=[0.74616534, 4.1743176523]
```

and

```
k=[0,1]
```

How to have this overlapping region:

```
[0.74616534, 1]
```

Or with:

```
r=[-2.74616534, 0.1743176523]
```

it would give:

```
[0, 0.1743176523]
```

Or with:

```
r=[0.0002845, 0.9888455]
```

it would give:

```
[0.0002845, 0.9888455]
```

etc.

Is it possible, as simple as can be and without looping and comparing each combination of "start/end" points?
Working both on Matlab and GNU Octave (no exotic functions). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overlap is the range that starts from the *maximum* of the two minima, and ends at the *minimum* of the two maxima. If the two are in the reverse order, it's an empty set.

E.g.

```
r = [0.74616534, 4.1743176523];
k = [0, 1];
a = max (min (r), min (k));
b = min (max (r), max (k));
if a <= b; Range = [a, b]; else; Range = []; end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need to sleep... Just a little precision; if a==b then it's no more a "range" in its strict meaning, but only a point. Well, a point may be seen as a special range of length=0. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The range in common between [-1,0] and [0,1] would be a single point at [0]